# Xcode 8 beta 2 installation error

Tags: ios, xcode

I've downloaded Xcode 8, Beta 2 several times and attempted to install it. Each time, I've encountered the following error when attempting to decompress the file:

`The operation couldn't be completed. cpio read error: Undefined error: 0`

**What I've tried:**

1. Googling suggested I might have a space issue, so I went medieval on my hard drive and cleared out 40 gigs. The file is a fraction of that, even uncompressed.
2. I ran Onyx and cleaned everything, ran maintenance scripts, repaired permissions, etc.
3. Multiple downloads, thinking perhaps a download might have been corrupted.

Any other suggestions re: what might get this thing working?

Comment: The file (`Xcode_8_beta_2.xip`) should be 4430818532 bytes and the output of `shasum` should be `8bf8d4e3810c7f96fa6788c69585899ec4151223`. What do you get?

Comment: I typed `shasum Xcode_8_beta_2.xip` and I get no diff--> `8bf8d4e3810c7f96fa6788c69585899ec4151223  Xcode_8_beta_2.xip`. https://www.diffnow.com/?report=ues3a

Comment: Try `xar -xvf Xcode_8_beta_2.xip`. What do you get? The result should be two files named `Content` and `Metadata`.

Comment: @robmayoff Thank you for your help on this. I freed up just a little more room and the file finally uncompressed without an error. I'm not sure why I needed so much room, but I finally got it open.

Comment: I have 890GB free space but still shows same error.

Comment: @robmayoff What to do with Content and Metadata file after using provided command. please advise

Comment: Nothing. I wanted to know if there was something wrong with his system that prevented it from decompressing the file.

Comment: In my case I just upgraded my mac to 10.11.5 and it works

Comment: same here, upgrading to 10.11.5 worked. I have 400+gb of free space

Comment: Under 16GB of free space is enough. Upgrading to 10.11.5 fixed my case. Seems there's a bug in some free space measuring function which has been fixed in 10.11.5.

Comment: About Xcode 8 beta 2
     Supported Configurations
          Xcode 8 beta 2 requires a Mac running macOS version 10.11.5 or later.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found another 500 megs of files to delete, bringing my free space to 40.5 GB. Upon attempting to open the ~4.5 GB `Xcode_8_beta_2.xip` after freeing it up the extra space, I was able to uncompress the archive.

I'm leaving here in case someone else encounters the same problem. This version seems to need significantly more free space than past versions I've installed.

Comment: I have 75 GB of free space, and it still holds onto it's `Undefined error: 0`. Damn!

Comment: Make sure you are running 10.11.5 and have over 40 GB of free space.

Comment: You don't need that much space btw. I only had 17GB and it was fine. I tried it with 10.11.6.

Comment: I have 267 GB. Still getting this error.

Comment: Xcode_8_beta_6 only required update to OSX 10.11.5, I had 15 GB free disk-space.

Comment: The [release notes for Xcode 8](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Introduction.html) final say 10.11.5 is required.

Comment: @Abras you saved my day! thanks.